# How do I batch plot drawings in monochrome without editing DWG?

Tags: autocad

I'm using AutoCAD 2015, and I run into this all the time.  I'm given a group of DWG drawings, and I want to plot them into one monochrome PDF, but they do not have monochrome.ctb selected as the plot style.  Is there any way in Batch Plot to publish to PDF using monochrome without editing the individual DWG files?  If not, is there a way to edit the page setup of all the drawings together as a group?

Comment: If you shift-click to select all the pages and then change the page setup, does it apply the monochrome settings to all selected pages?

Comment: @grfrazee That does work.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Good to know.  It looks like you've been able to fill out a more detailed answer below, so I'll leave you to that :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing around with it for a while, this seems to work:

1. In the Batch Plot dialog, add all the drawings/sheets you want to include:

[image: Batch Plot dialog]

In the picture above, you can see that different drawings have different default Page Setups.  None of these drawings have a page setup I can use.

2. Select the first drawing, and under Page Setup, select "Import..."

[image: Select "Import..."]

3. Choose a DWG file that does contain a page setup you like.  In my case, I'm looking for one that will plot the Extents of the model using the monochrome.ctb plot style.
4. Your imported Page Setups are now available in the list.  Select the one you want.  In my case, I'm choosing the one called "Imported: 11x17".

[image: Select the Page Setup]

5. Select this Page Setup for each drawing.  You can select all the sheets at once (Ctrl-A, or Shift-Click) and then choose a page setup.
6. Save the Sheet List.  This will preserve your imported Page Setup for the entire list, so you won't need to do these steps in the future for these drawings.
7. Click the Publish button to plot the drawings.

This procedure doesn't make any changes to the DWG files.  In the future, you can load the Sheet List, and the imported Page Setups will still be selected.